# how to hold new request when old request is processing in flask?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, request, semaphore

I created a python app in flask. Here the Skelton of the code

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def authentication():
    '''athentication process'''
    return 'authenticated'
```

so when user call the app it will authenticate. but if two user call that at same time or while processing one authentication i want to hold the new request until the old one finished then I want to start the new request. I've tried with `semaphore` but not working. Here is what I've tried

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def authentication():
        sem.acquire()
        '''athentication process'''
        sem.release()
        return 'authenticated'
```

and I have deployed this in `Heroku`. Any idea how I can achieve this?

**PS: If this can't be done at least i want to response the new request that another request is in process and try again after some time**

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: Dont worry about it.

This is the job of a web server. When you host the application in any Server like Apache , Nginx etc the server creates multiple processes of your flask app.When requst comes the, server program forwards it to any of the free processes, if no process is free server will queue the request until one process becomes free.
This is high level overwiew of how HTTP servers work.

Comment: No it doesn't seems to be working on heroku server (I use only one worker)

Comment: i dont know about heroku , but this is defenetily not a Flask issue, it has to be handled on http server. Youll be beter of checking heroku docs to scale up the server , there will be some config you can set to fix your issue